# Effective windows password management for offices

Tags: password-management

I need to find password management software which meets these requirements:

- Shared database (only need to access / update one location)
- User / Group based permissions (can hide certain groups of passwords from certain users)
- Password expiry reminders

Would also be lovely to have:

- Access locked down to only certain windows logins (ie location specific, employees can't copy the DB onto a stick and use it at home)

So far I've found [KeyPass](http://keepass.info/) and [Password Manager XP](http://www.cp-lab.com/) can anyone recommend other solutions?

Comment: I would not suggest you to use KeePass and let people simultaneously access the same database file.

Comment: Any other suggestions though? ^^

Answer (score 0):

As I've mentioned before, the problem of a single database file is that it can easily get corrupted and with KeePass, every password in the file is accessible to everybody, so nothing for groups. It does have lock files, but I wouldn't completely trust them to lock a database against incoherent changes.

---

You might want to check out [PassPack](http://www.passpack.com/en/home/):

> Passpack lets you store personal, work and client logins in one master list, then choose what to share with whom and when.
>
> All updates are automatically synchronized.
>
> You may change settings, share passwords and set permissions in bulk or on a single record; one user at a time or with entire user groups.

[image]

There is a free version, but the Pro and Group versions are relatively cheap at $1.50 or $4 a month, respectively. [No, I'm not affiliated with them, it's just a solution to your problem ;)]

This would also effectively hinder people to just "copy the DB on a stick".